Can we highlight all the file currently opened in vscode in the sidebar explorer tree
I know that there is this setting to highlight the active file in vscode
`
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#215d48",
  },

Explanation -
Assume there are 10 files currently opened in VS Code, But I have only one file in the current view rest are opened but are not in the viewing state, just like in any browser, there me 10 tabs open but at a time only one is being viewed. what I am trying is to see all the 10 files to be highlighted in VS Code sidebar tree.
Expected - What I am trying to get is, can I highlight all the currently open tabs/file in the sidebar explorer as well?
Since there is already a section to see all the current opened file I thought there might be some setting to also highlight those open files in the sidebar tree.
I tried this
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#215d48",
  },

But this only highlights the current file open, what I am trying is to highlight all the files which are opened

Have you taken a look at the documentation? See: VSCode theme color docs - if none of those refer to all opened documents then this does not exist yet. You can open a feature request on the VSCode issue tracker - of course make sure it's not asked yet.

Thanks for the idea, I raised a feature request.
Cheers!

why not just look at the open editors view? also, please add a link to your issue ticket.

I wanted to see where the opened files are located in the tree structure, instead of manually hunting for and matching their folder paths, which often confuses me with things like ../../../. By the way, here’s the issue link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/233870

In case if anyone is looking for the Reddit's post link - https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/1h76106/feature_request_highlight_all_open_files_in_vs/
